# Converting degrees-minutes to radians from data in a text file

Tags: python, string, math, coordinate-transformation

For example in my text file, [Data.txt](http://pastebin.com/fdKPxidx):

```
AB     N05-30-00E      495.85        
BC     N46-02-00E      850.62       
CD     S67-38-00E      855.45       
DE     S12-25-00E     1020.87      
EF     S83-44-00W     1117.26     
FA     N55-09-00W      660.08
```

These are the sides, bearing and the length/distance respectively. How can I convert this to radians? (after that I will get the latitude and departures, but I will do that later if only I could get this one first) Then I write a txt file with the results, the fourth and fifth are the latitude and departure.

```
import math

fileread = open("Data.txt","r")
data = fileread.read
#missing code, convert the string to degrees decimal?
print "%.3f" %  math.cos(math.radians())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  Jay Kominek is right.

Just add to his answer.

1. Created function according Jay Kominek answer.
2. Read input file by `CSV` modules because file is well structured.
3. Calculate output and write Row in to output file.

**input**:

```
AB  N05-30-00E  495.85
BC  N46-02-00E  850.62
CD  S67-38-00E  855.45
DE  S12-25-00E  1020.87
EF  S83-44-00W  1117.26
FA  N55-09-00W  660.08
```

**Demo**:

```
import csv
import math
import re


def convertRedis(format_input):
    """
        Coordinate format conversion
    degrees minutes seconds: 
    decimal degrees = degrees + minutes}/60 + seconds/3600. 
    """
    degrees, minutes, seconds = map(float, re.match("\w(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)\w", format_input).groups())
    degrees = degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600
    return math.radians(degrees)


with open("Technical Description.txt") as fp:
    root_r = csv.reader(fp)
    root_r = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t')
    with open("output.txt", "wb+") as fp2:
        root_w = csv.writer(fp2, delimiter='\t')
        for row in root_r:
            rads = convertRedis(row[1])
            new_row = list(row)
            distance = float(row[2])
            if "S" in row[1]:
                d_cos =  "%.2f"%(distance*math.cos(rads) * -1, )
            else:
                d_cos =  "%.2f"%(distance*math.cos(rads), )

            if "W" in row[1]:
                d_sin =  "%.2f"%(distance*math.sin(rads) * -1, )
            else:
                d_sin =  "%.2f"%(distance*math.sin(rads), )

            new_row.extend([d_sin, d_cos])
            root_w.writerow(new_row)
```

Output:

```
AB  N05-30-00E  495.85  47.53   493.57
BC  N46-02-00E  850.62  612.23  590.53
CD  S67-38-00E  855.45  791.09  -325.53
DE  S12-25-00E  1020.87 219.51  -996.99
EF  S83-44-00W  1117.26 -1110.58    -121.96
FA  N55-09-00W  660.08  -541.70 377.19
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what your data presents, so this is just a rough hint at the string conversion part:

```
# s = "05-30-00"
(degrees, minutes, seconds) = \
   map(float, re.match("(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)", s).groups())
```

Once you've got `degrees`, `minutes`, and `seconds`, you "flatten" them into a single value:

```
degrees = degrees + minutes / 60.0 + seconds / 3600.0
```

finally,

```
rads = math.radians(degrees)
```

will finish that conversion, as you hinted.

Depending on what you're doing with it, you might want to flip the sign, based on the compass direction, like:

```
if compass in ('W', 'S'):
  degrees = -degrees
```

For more details on the conversions, lookup "[Geographic coordinate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion)".